# How does XOR prevent NULL bytes in shellcode

Tags: c, assembly, shellcode, execve

I had been trying to follow this tutorial (https://paraschetal.in/writing-your-own-shellcode) on how to write your own shellcode. 99% of it makes sense to me but there is just two lingering doubts in my mind - this relates to writing shellcode in general

Firstly, I think I understand *why* we want to avoid the null byte but *how* does using the following avoid null bytes?

```
xor eax, eax
```

Doesn't `eax` now contain exactly null bytes? Or does it contain 0s? When we XOR something with itself, it returns False, correct?

Secondly, the tutorial says:

> Finally, we’ll load the syscall number(11 or 0xb) to the eax
>   register. However if we use eax in our instruction, the resulting
>   shellcode will contain some NULL(\x00) bytes and we don’t want that.
>   Our eax register already is NULL. So we’ll just load the syscall
>   number to the al register instead of the entire eax register.

```
mov byte  al, 0x0b
```

Now I do understand what is going on here, the number 11 (for `execve`) is being loaded into the first 8 bits of `eax` register (which is `al`). But the rest of `eax` still contains null bytes so what exactly is achieved here?

Please note, I've come here as a last resort after spending most of the day trying to understand this, so please take it easy on me :)

Comment: The point is to avoid the zero byte in the machine code itself, not in the register at runtime. If you write `mov eax, 0` it will have the zero in the payload. `xor eax, eax` happens to have a machine code that does not include a zero byte, but at runtime it will produce a zero as required. Just create the payload for the two versions and observe the zero bytes.

Comment: You're very much contradicting yourself by saying you "fully understand" why null bytes be avoided and then you confuse them with register values...

Comment: Apologies, will edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exploits usually attack C code, and therefore the *shell code* often needs to be delivered in a *NUL-terminated string*. If the shell code contains NUL bytes the C code that is being exploited might *ignore* and drop rest of the code starting from the *first zero byte*.

This concerns only the *machine code*. If you need to call the system call with number 0xb, then naturally you need to be able to produce the number 0xb in the EAX register, but you can only use those forms of machine code that do not contain zero bytes in the machine code itself.

---

```
xor eax, eax
```

will invert all the 1 *bits* in the `eax`, i.e. *zero* it. It is a functional equivalent to

```
mov eax, 0
```

except that the latter *will* have the 0 coded as zero bytes in the *machine code*.

---

The machine code for

```
xor eax, eax
mov byte al, 0x0b
```

is

```
31 c0 b0 0b
```

As you can see, there are no embedded zero bytes in it. The machine code for

```
mov eax, 0xb
```

is

```
b8 0b 00 00 00
```

Both these programs are functionally equivalent in that they set the value of EAX register to 0xb.

If the latter shell code is handled as a null-terminated string by a C program, the rest of it after the `b8 0b 00` could be discarded by the program and be replaced by other bytes in the memory, essentially making the shellcode not work.

Comment: Follow up question: in essence, eax contains bytes semantically equivalent to a null byte but without containing actual null bytes, correct?

Comment: @ak1652 **The only concern is that the shell code cannot contain null bytes. To write the value `0` without using the digit `0`, you can write 1-1. The result is still 0. *WE WANT 0 AS THE RESULT*. Likewise EAX will contain null bytes, because we WANT it to have. We were just tasked to not use the digit 0 when *writing* it.**

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

The instruction `mov eax, 0` assembles to

```
b8 00 00 00 00
```

which contains NUL bytes. However, the instruction `xor eax, eax` assembles to

```
31 c0
```

which is free of NUL bytes, making it suitable for shell code.

The same applies to `mov al, 0x0b`.  If you do `mov eax, 0x0b`, the encoding is

```
b8 0b 00 00 00
```

which contains NUL bytes.  However, `mov al, 0x0b` encodes to

```
b0 0b
```

avoiding NUL bytes.